# Can one force dialogs to use the textual from when using the front end?

Tags: front-end, dialog-window, jupyter-notebook

The documentation for `ChoiceDialog` states that

> If Mathematica is run without a notebook front end, ChoiceDialog gives
>   choices in a textual form.

Indeed, one can use `ChoiceDialog` (but also `MessageDialog` and other dialogs) in codes that run without a front end without any significant modifications.

My question is whether one can somehow force this "textual form" despite using a front end? By "textual form" I mean that the content of a dialog (e.g. a `MessageDialog`) appears as a text in a cell, as if one would use `Print` or `WriteString`.

For dialogs that require user input that probably wouldn't work, but at least dialogs such as `MessageDialog` which merely display some infromation and wait for the OK button to be hit, it would be helpful.

This is mainly interesting for Jupyter notebooks, where Mathematica thinks that it runs in a valid front end, but actually as of now dialogs are [not supported](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/issues/78). So the only choice for a code that makes use of dialogs would be to abort the evaluation
once it detects Jupyter and force the user to switch to the kernel interface.

What I tried so far is the naive

```
Block[{$FrontEnd = Null}, MessageDialog["Hi"]]
```

but obviously this doesn't work.

If a solutions is possible, it would be nice if it also could work with the current [Wolfram Language kernel for Jupyter notebooks](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter).

Comment: Have you tried the "textual form" in a terminal? It allows you to type OK or Cancel in the terminal. When running with the FE, there is no terminal. There is no single insertion point, as with a traditional terminal. Thus this type of user interaction does not make sense, and is not possible. Compare `Input`, which can also read from the terminal, and check what it does with the FE: it puts up a dialog window.

Comment: If your main motivation is to use this with Jupyter notebooks, I'd suggest focusing the question directly on that. Right now this looks like almost an XY problem ... You did mention your actual motivation, but the title and the first half of the question sound exactly like trying to force the wrong solution to the actual problem. I suggest you edit the question.

Comment: If one could force a MessageDialog to use the textual form, that would already suffice, for the rest (e.g. ChoiceDialog) I could probably find some workarounds. But if even MessageDialog cannot be used this way, then I wouldn't expect a simple (i.e. minimally invasive) solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "use the textual form". The "textual form" you mentioned means "use the terminal for input". You are asking to use it when there is no terminal. That is contradictory. If what you actually want is some form of input with Jupyter notebooks, you should edit the question and ask that.

Comment: Ok, I clarified it in the question. However, I don't really expect that there is a simple workaround. Of course one could write a custom dialog that does what I'm looking for, but that would mean that existing codes must be heavily modified only to work with Jupyter. Perhaps I will just wait until dialog support is added to Jupyter.

Comment: "Perhaps I will just wait until dialog support is added to Jupyter." It might help if you open an issue on GitHub and request that feature.

Comment: I already [did](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/issues/78) but there is no way to estimate how much time will pass until this feature is added.

Comment: Have you thought about using [`Message`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html). It writes out to a generated cell. The code then proceeds as normal. [`Check`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) works well with `Message`.